# Spring PDF how to change first page's configuration

Tags: spring, pdf, itext

I want to use a PDF page as the view. So I extend AbstractPdfView, and override the function buildPdfDocument. However, I encounter a problem.

I want change my PDF view to landscape. But the default layout is portrait. When I change the attribute to landscape, the pages will be landscape just from second page, and the first page is always portrait.

In the book iText in action, the author said that "Many settings, such as the page size and margins, only go into effect on the next page. This may seem trivial, but it’s a common question for new iText users. If you want the feature to work on page 1, define it before opening the document."

But in function buildPdfDocument, the document is already opened. So I want to know how can I change the first page's configuration. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just override newDocument method in your class:

```
@Override
protected Document newDocument() {
  return new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
}
```